# How to make Android UIAutomator continue test when assertEquals failed?

Tags: android, junit, android-uiautomator

Say the case:

```kotlin
   // ./gradlew -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.demo.Debug#debug connectedAndroidTest
    @Test
    fun debug() {
        assertEquals("n", "N")
        assertEquals("hello", "Hello")
    }
```

And the test would break when `assertEquals("n", "N")` failed.

I was wondering how to make it continue to test the `assertEquals("hello", "Hello")` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for 2 conditions that can be satisfied independently use

```
assertTrue("n" == "N" || "hello" == "Hello")
```